# OSError : [ WinError 10049 ] Требуемый адрес для своего контекста неверен

Tags: python

Помогите, уже 3 часа не могу понять в чем трабл.

```
import socket
import time
from threading import *

from Logic.Device import Device
from Logic.Player import Player
from Protocol.LogicMessageFactory import packets


def _(*args):
    print('[INFO]', end=' ')
    for arg in args:
        print(arg, end=' ')
    print()


print(r"""

Server 
                                                               V28.189                                                                 
""")


class Server:
    def __init__(self, ip: str, port: int):
        self.server = socket.socket()
        self.port = port
        self.ip = ip
        
    def start(self):
        self.server.bind((self.ip, self.port))
        _(f'Server started! Ip: {self.ip}, Port: {self.port}')
        while True:
            self.server.listen()
            client, address = self.server.accept()
            _(f'New connection! Ip: {address[0]}')
            ClientThread(client, address).start()


class ClientThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, client, address):
        super().__init__()
        self.client = client
        self.address = address
        self.device = Device(self.client)
        self.player = Player(self.device)

    def recvall(self, length: int):
        data = b''
        while len(data) < length:
            s = self.client.recv(length)
            if not s:
                print("ERROR while receiving data!")
                break
            data += s
        return data

    def run(self):
        last_packet = time.time()
        while True:
            header = self.client.recv(7)
            if len(header) > 0:
                last_packet = time.time()
                packet_id = int.from_bytes(header[:2], 'big')
                length = int.from_bytes(header[2:5], 'big')
                data = self.recvall(length)

                if packet_id in packets:
                    _(f'Received packet! Id: {packet_id}')
                    message = packets[packet_id](self.client, self.player, data)
                    message.decode()
                    message.process()
                else:
                    _(f'Packet not handled! ({packet_id})')
            if time.time() - last_packet > 10:
                _("Client disconnected!")
                self.client.close()
                break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = Server('5*.**.*3*.***', 9339)
    server.start()
```

Comment: Я спецально скрыл свой ip.

Comment: А вы точно указываете в качестве IP адреса именно IP который у машинки, на которой запускаете Server? А то может вы пытаетесь сделать bind на IP вашего роутера, если сервер находится, скажем за NAT'ом.

Comment: Я указываю и менно тот айпи, который у сервера.